# qfiledialog - Filtering Folders?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qfiledialog

1)I want to get the name of the folder for a folder monitoring Application..
Is there a way that i can filter out specific folders from being displayed using QFileDialog (For example i don't want the my documents to be displayed in the file dialog)..

2)I don't want the user to select a drive. By default in this code drives can also be selected..

```
dirname=QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,'Open Directory','c:\\',QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
print(dirname)
```

Is there a way that i can gray out the drives or some specific folders so that it can't be selected or can i set the filters for folder to prevent showing it up..

Answer (score 9):

You can try setting a proxy model for your file dialog: [QFileDialog::setProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#setProxyModel). In the proxy model class override the [filterAcceptsRow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filterAcceptsRow) method and return false for folders which you don't want to be shown. Below is an example of how proxy model can look like; it'c c++, let me know if there are any problems converting this code to python. This model is supposed to filter out files and show only folders:

```
class FileFilterProxyModel : public QSortFilterProxyModel
{
protected:
    virtual bool filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex& source_parent) const;
};

bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    QFileSystemModel* fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());

    if (fileModel!=NULL && fileModel->isDir(index0))
    {
        qDebug() << fileModel->fileName(index0);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    // uncomment to execute default implementation
    //return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);
}
```

here's how I was calling it

```
QFileDialog dialog;
FileFilterProxyModel* proxyModel = new FileFilterProxyModel;
dialog.setProxyModel(proxyModel);
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
dialog.exec();
```

Note that the proxy model is supported by non-native file dialogs only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using QDir.Dirs filter.

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(parentWidget)

dialog.setFilter(QDir.Dirs)
```

Comment: Thanks apt for your reply. But it'll list all the directories.. Here i want to list only the patricular directories..The above code also does the same.. My question is Like file extension filter is there any filter for directories?? And one more question is there a way the "ok button in qfiledialog" can be disabled when the user selects a patricular directory..

Answer (score 1):

serge_gubenko gave you the right answer. You only had to check the folder names and return "false" for the ones which should not be displayed. For instance, to filter out any folders named "private" you'd write:

```
bool FileFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    QFileSystemModel* fileModel = qobject_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());

    if (fileModel!=NULL && fileModel->isDir(index0))
    {
        qDebug() << fileModel->fileName(index0);
        if (QString::compare(fileModel->fileName(index0), tr("private")) == 0)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    // uncomment to execute default implementation
    //return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);
}
```

I already tested this and it works perfectly.
serge_gubenko should receive all due credit.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you were asking, but if you're working with a QFileSystemModel, you can do it with the Name Filters option.

```
model = QFileSystemModel()
model.setNameFilters(["[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890]*"])
model.setNameFilterDisables(False)
```

It worked for me, and I couldn't find the answer anywhere else on the internet, so I figured I post it here.

(I know my regex is trash, but using [\\w\\d]* didn't work and I was feeling lazy.)