# QT QFileDialog how to hide hidden/backup folders (".folder")

Tags: hidden, qfiledialog, qt4.6, getopenfilename

Basically when browsing folders inside a QFileDialog I find very annoying to have everything bloated with hidden or backup folders (don't know how to call them really); specially on home.

Is there a way to prevent these type of folders from showing by default on a QFileDialog?

I'm using Qt4.6 and getOpenFileName.

P.D.: I'm starting to think this might be an ubuntu thing...?

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux only sporadically, but I believe the "." is just a convention which file managers use to hide files. Probably you'll have to write code to explicitly filter out folder names.

Check out [qfiledialog - Filtering Folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101100/qfiledialog-filtering-folders)