# QFileDialog showing hidden files although system setting is off

Tags: c++, qt, hidden-files, opendialog

I am using the following code to show an open dialog in Qt:

```
QString path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Config File"), QDir::rootPath(), "Text Files (*.txt *.csv *.*);;");
```

What I realised is that this dialog also shows hidden files although the system setting for showing hidden files is turned off. It's the same if I instantiate the `QFileDialog` manually and show it. I also couldn't find out how to turn this off via a filter.

Does anyone know if there is a way to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: I just tried it on ubuntu and here it seems the other way around: it never shows hidden files. But I don't know if there is something like a system wide setting for this on Linux.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Windows 7 and Qt 4.8.5. I see the native file dialog and its content corresponds to the system's settings.

Comment: I'm also using Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no simple(by setting some flag) solution out there. So I recommend to use the filtering which is described in other SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101100/qfiledialog-filtering-folders).
But in your case you might use the following condition:

```
if(fileModel != nullptr)
{
    QFileInfo info = fileModel->fileInfo(index0);
    return info.isHidden();
}
return false;
```

Comment: Hm...ok. I think if this is really a Qt-problem I'm going to let it be for now. If I used your solution I still would have to find out what the system setting is and then act accordingly. Maybe they fix it in on of the next releases. It's not that much of a problem, just very annoying for the user.

Comment: I don't think it is a problem at all. The settings you are talking about are the Explorer settings and I don't see why other apps should regard these settings.

Comment: On the other hand Qt claims it uses native dialog by default and if that's the case then Explorer settings should be acknowledged. Strange.

Comment: Well, unlike on Linux there is only one file browser on Windows so I think the settings the user selects there should be respected everywhere, especially if it's a supposedly 'native' file dialog.